Motivation and history of Fubini's theorem
I saw the double integral version of Fubini's theorem on Wikipedia.

It was introduced by Guido Fubini in 1907. It states that if a function is Lebesgue integrable on a rectangle ${\displaystyle X\times Y}$, then one can evaluate the double integral as an iterated integral y using an iterated integral.
$${\displaystyle \,\iint \limits _{X\times Y}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}(x,y)=\int _{X}\left(\int _{Y}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}y\right){\text{d}}x=\int _{Y}\left(\int _{X}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}x\right){\text{d}}y.}$$
The formula is, in general, not true for the Riemann integral, but it is true if the function is continuous on the rectangle. In multivariable calculus, this weaker result is sometimes also called Fubini's theorem, although it was already known by Leonhard Euler.

And after looking into it further, I found that there is also a  double series version.

A related theorem is often called Fubini's theorem for infinite series, although it is due to Alfred Pringsheim this theorem states that if ${\textstyle \{a_{m,n}\}_{m=1,n=1}^{\infty }}$ is a double-indexed sequence of real numbers, and if ${\textstyle \displaystyle \sum _{(m,n)\in \mathbb {N} \times \mathbb {N} }a_{m,n}}$ is absolutely convergent, then ${\displaystyle \sum _{(m,n)\in \mathbb {N} \times \mathbb {N} }a_{m,n}=\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m,n}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }a_{m,n}}$ Although Fubini's theorem for infinite series is a special case of the more general Fubini's theorem, it is not necessarily appropriate to characterize the former as being proven by the latter because the properties of measures needed to prove Fubini's theorem proper, in particular subadditivity of measure, may be proven using Fubini's theorem for infinite series.

I became interested in Fubini's theorem when I saw these various types of Fubini's theorem. So I'm curious about the history of what Fubini had in mind when he first created the double integral version of Fubini's theorem and how he developed the theory.

This is the kind of question that deserves many answers, so this is just one fragment of an attempt at a contribution.
Pringsheim not only proved the double series version in 1900, he in fact stated the commutative exchange of integrated integrals as potential equality to a double integral  (today the identities known as Fubini's theorem) in 1898 and 1899 (the German "Zur Theorie des Doppel-Integrals" translates to "On the theory of double integration"):

Pringsheim, A. (1898). Zur Theorie des Doppel-Integrals. Munich
Kön.-bayer. Akad. d. Wissensch.

(I could not find an online version of the first publicaiton though I'm sure someone more patient can find it.) and

Pringsheim, A. (1899). Zur Theorie des Doppel-Integrals, des Green’schen
und Cauchy’schen Integralsatzes. Sitzungsberichte der mathematisch-physikalischen Classe der k. b. Akademie der Wissenschaften zu München, Heft I. p. 39-61.

Note that the beginning of the paper opens with what today is known as Fubini's theorem.
Pringsheim purpose is to probe these identities with respect to conditions for existence and non-existence. All this is in the sense of Riemann integration. He proves possibility of non-existence by counter-example. In a sense Pringsheim shows that careless use of the identities is not a theorem in the Riemann setting.
Pringsheim (1899) is actually also a decent source for historical traces. He notes Stolz (1886) pointing out false claims of integrability conditions for double integration.
This of course predates Lebesgue integration, and Fubini would then prove that existence is guaranteed in the Lebesque setting. In a sense for Pringsheim it's a problem space (something that should not be a theorem), and in Fubini it's a theorem.
Historical developments of ideas leading up to Lebesque can be found in:

Hawkins, T. (1975). Lebesgue's theory of integration: its origins and
development. 2nd ed. Chelsea.

You will find discussion of apparent failures of exchange of integrals to fail in Cauchy discussed here.
See also:

Paunić, D. (2002). History of measure theory. in Pap. (ed) Handbook
of Measure Theory (Two volumes). Elsevier, pages 1-26.

The question of motivation is probably well answered in numerous ways by the historical discussion on evolution of questions of integration in:

Bottazzini, U., & Gray, J. J. (2013). Hidden Harmony: Geometric
Fantasies. Springer.

Where one can find extensive discussion of double integrals through its historical development. It is a ripe source of historical motivations on the question. I'll just quote one:

Cauchy built on this work, and to explain some of its paradoxical
conclusions made a detailed study of the introduction of imaginaries
in his Memoir (Cauchy 1814, first published 1827). There he showed
that the reduction of a double integral to a repeated integral can be
affected by the presence of singular integrals, an insight that was
eventually to be the key to the theory of integrating a complex
function on a closed path.

To close the circle (pun intended) consider the following reference for bringing Cauchy integrals back to Pringsham's work on double integrals:
Gray, J. (2000). Goursat, Pringsheim, Walsh, and the Cauchy Integral Theorem. Mathematical Intelligencer, 22(4).

Hello, thank you for your answer! I have read the book (Bottazzini, U., & Gray, J. J. (2013). Hidden Harmony: Geometric Fantasies. Springer) you recommended. If you read pp.644-647, Pringsheim seems to have considered the Cauchy integral theorem and Green's theorem. Can I assume that Pringsheim's work on the prototype of Fubini's theorem is an extension of this interest?

@user1274233 In a way it's the opposite. Pringsheim considers "Fubini's theorem" to show that there is trouble in naive use of it (pre-Lebesque) and applies it to Cauchy integrals (think of the complex integral in the plane) and Green's theorem (integral relating the boundary to the interior). The way Bottazzini and Gray look at it is with respect to evolution of the latter problems and not directly as history towards Fubini's proof.

Thank you very much for your comment. However, I am more curious about when Pringsheim came up with Fubini's theorem. In your answer above, you wrote Pringsheim purpose is to probe these identities with respect to conditions for existence and non-existence.. Could you tell me the source? I tried to find it, but it was hard to find.

The sources are cited in my answer, and one is linked to. For that source you will find the identities on the first page.

I'm really sorry that I keep bothering you. However, I do not understand exactly what Pringsheim means by existence. And this is a side question, but I would like to know more about the background of why Pringsheim created the prototype of Fubini's theorem to solve a situation where something was missing mathematically and to fill in something mathematically lacking.

If you could recommend any reference books that could help me solve my concerns, I would really appreciate it.

Sadly I don't really have anything to recommend beyond what is already in my original answer. There is no single source that I know of that summarized the (pre)-history of Fubini's theorem but numerous sources I provided touch on aspect of it. With sufficient time with the given sources you should be able to form a kind of an answer to numerous aspects of your question though as I indicated in my answer too there is likely more than my answer alone can provide. Perhaps someone else will chime in and provide additional information and perspectives.

Okay, I understand. Thank you so much for leaving a comment, even though I kept bothering you.
